# Only first item in bootstrap accordion is collapsing - z-index problem

Tags: bootstrap-4, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

Only the first item in my accordion is working.... I haven't touched the HTML code yes, only the css for now... 
I used the working example in bootstrap website but as soon as I styled it, it got messed up...

the problem is the Z-INDEX. When I tried it without using z-index, it worked great. The problem is I need the z-index in order to hide each top of an element behind the bottom rounded border of the element before it.

Is there a way to do what I need without using the z-index property?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card" id="historyCard">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                                היסטוריה
                                            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="whoWeAreCard">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                                מי אנחנו?
                                            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="numbersCard">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                "בשבילי" במספרים"
                                            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="sayingCard">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                צעירים אומרים...
                                            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card" id="contactCard">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                                צור קשר
                                            </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

can anyone take a look?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow  Please post the code or create code pan so that we can help you. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through this and learn how to post a minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Mabye this is a silly question but are you online when you're testing.  I once had a problem with menus until I realised that there was a reference to a remote js file

Comment: yes I'm online :)

Comment: @bargabbai Updated the answer s per your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for accordion collapse when you click on a div. For this you need to wrap your accordion code inside the button which has `data-toggle` . Keep in mind that you need to set the `card-body` `margin-body` to highest negative margin-top of your card id

```css
.card {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
}

#historyCard {
  background-color: #ffb59b;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  z-index: 5
}

#whoWeAreCard {
  background-color: #ffe285;
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  z-index: 4
}

#numbersCard {
  background-color: #9abada;
  margin-top: -90px; /*highest -ve margin top */
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: 3
}

.card-body {
  margin-bottom: 90px; /* set this according to the margin-top of card id and this should be of positive value*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="card" id="historyCard">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">

            1

          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsetwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="card" id="whoWeAreCard">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
          <h5 class="mb-0">

            2

          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div id="collapsetwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsethree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="width: 100%">
      <div class="card" id="numbersCard">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
          <h5 class="mb-0">

            3

          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div id="collapsethree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 0


Well, that wasn't it... I do have different data-target for each collapsable... The problem is with the z-index of each collapsable element. when I removed the z-index it helped. but still - I need every item beneath the other one. I still can't find the answer to that without using z-index.

Comment: I didn't use any z-index and it works good for me.  And your `id="collapseFive"` has  `data-target="#collapseThree"`. Please update your question with your requirement by posting the `css`   as it would be difficult to assess your code without css

Comment: yes thats the problem - when I don't use z-index, it works fine... but I do need the z-index.

Comment: @bargabbai please post the piece of code which wasn't working

Comment: of course, I posted it in a comment. Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

this is the piece of code that makes the other clickable item not work (marked with 2 *):

```
       .card{
        border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
        border:none;
    }

    #historyCard {
        background-color: #ffb59b;
        margin-top:-50px;
        padding-top:60px;
    }

    #whoWeAreCard {
        background-color: #ffe285;
        margin-top: -80px;
        padding-top: 70px;
        **z-index: -1;**
    }

    #numbersCard {
        background-color: #9abada;
        margin-top: -90px;
        padding-top: 80px;
        **z-index: -2;**
    }

    #sayingCard {
        background-color: #8adffa;
        margin-top: -100px;
        padding-top: 90px;
        **z-index: -3;**
    }

    #contactCard {
        background-color: #ffcd9b;
        margin-top: -110px;
        padding-top: 100px;
        **z-index: -4;**
    }
```

is there another way to make one element behind another except z-index? cause it seems to like hide the link or something...

here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/81co7502/

Comment: as you see there are no links to click on your collapse as you have applied negative margin

Comment: but the header of each element, which is also the link, still shows... also,,, the negative margin is working fine, the z-index is the line which makes it not clickable.. so what am I missing here? is there another wat to put each element behind another without using z-index?